# Show that the elements $x^iy^j$ such that $i=0,1,2,3$ and $j=0,1$ are distinct elements of $G$, and hence constitute all elements of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

There exists a group $G$ of order $8$ having two generators $x,y:x^4=y^2=e$ and $xy=yx^3$.

I found that $G=\{e,y,x,xy,x^2,x^2y,x^3,x^3y\}$
But how to show that these elements are distinct? Is saying that $|G|=8$ enough? Or maybe I should check all 56 possibilities and show that at that case $|G|<8$? Also I don't understand how to show that we have all elements of $G$ by checking only for $0\leq i\leq 3$ and $0\leq j\leq 1$? Maybe there are other distinct element for some finite combination $xxyyxyyxyxyy...xyyx$?

I just want to know intuitively what I can do with groups and what I can't. So I need answers, and some of them may seem stupid to you, but I just need them and that's all.

Comment: I'm on the first paragraph of the chapter. I'm not supposed to know that yet, and I'd liked to solve it without $D_4$.

Comment: Should your title read "Show that the elements $x^iy^j$ such that...?

Comment: @graydad What would you advice?
Ok, I got it and think I will do smth

Comment: At this point I am just suggesting making the change $$x_iy_i \to x^iy^j$$ since we talk about elements of this group as $x$ or $y$ raised to a power and/or multiplied together, not with subscript notation. As for showing each element is distinct, I feel that the fact that you calculated out every possibility by hand, and end up with $8$ suffices.

Comment: @graydad Ok. But how do you know that $x^7y^5x^{15}y^{99}$ is not 9th element of a group?

Comment: I see what you are saying. First of all, that would mean $G$ isn't a group of order $8$. As for your example element, you can use the identities $x^4 = e=y^2$, so that $$x^7y^5x^{15}y^{99} = (x^4x^3)((y^2)^2y)((x^4)^3x)((y^2)^{49}y) \\ = (ex^3)((e)^2y)((e)^3x)((e)^{49}y) \\  = x^3yxy$$ and now use $xy = yx^3$ to get $$ x^3yxy=x^3y(yx^3) \\ = x^3ex^3 \\ = x^6 \\ = ex^2 \\ = x^2$$ Which is already an element you found in $G$

Comment: @graydad So I think that it will be better to prove that in general that $x_1^{k_1}y_1^{l_1}...x_n^{k_n}y_m^{l_m}$ is already in group.
btw are you sure that checking all 56 possibilities is necessary? It's so strange.

Comment: No I'm saying checking all $56$ is not necessary haha. That would be pretty ridiculous (or unfair in my opinion, if this was for a professor). Your idea of a proof seems reasonable, although I think you can generalize and argue that $x^iy^j \in G$ for all $i \in \{0,1,2,3\}, \space j \in \{0,1\}$. I can write up an answer to summarize some options if you'd like?

Comment: @graydad I'd like to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a product of $x$'s and $y$'s in $G$. Repeatedly using $xy = yx^3$, we can move all the $x^k$ to the front of the product, giving us something of the form $x^iy^j$, where $i$ and $j$ are integers. Now using $x^4 = 1$ and $y^2 = 1$, we can arrange it so that $i \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $j \in \{0,1\}$. Since we can always do this beginning with any finite product, we deduce that $|G| \le 8$.

Now, suppose there are some $i,k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $j,\ell\in\{0,1\}$ so that $x^iy^j = x^ky^\ell$ in $G$. Multiply on the left by $x^{-k}$ and on the right by $y^{-j}$. We see that $x^{i-k} = y^{j-\ell}$. The only equations we know that will let us deduce this are $x^4 = y^2 = e$, so we conclude $i-k =j-\ell = 0$. Thus $i = k$ and $j = \ell$, and we conclude $|G|=8$.

---

As an aside, I don't *love* the second paragraph as an argument for when you're first learning about groups. The idea I had behind it was that the equations that we are given are assumed to be enough to deduce any equality that is true in $G$. A nicer way to prove that there is such a group of order 8 is, as you say, to discuss $D_4$; show it satisfies the equations and has 8 elements.